# Build R package with C Code for Linux and Windows

Tags: r

I have been doing research and I can't quite figure out how to build my R package, that calls C functions, in order for it to work in both Windows and Linux environments.  I am building the package on a Linux machine.

I have two C files, one.C and two.C, I place the two files in the src directory after using package.skeleton(...).  In the namespace file I use the command: useDynLib(one,two).  Is this correct?  Or do I need to put the actual function names instead of the file names?  Do I need to export the function names?

Do I need to put the .so files in the src directory or will these be created automatically?  I am worried then it won't work on a windows machine which needs a .dll file.

As you can see I'm a little confused, thanks for the help.

Comment: In the NAMESPACE file `useDynLib(mypkg)` rather than one, two. This works on all platforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the standard R manuals is [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html). Part of this manual is the section [5 System and foreign language interfaces](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#System-and-foreign-language-interfaces). This will probably answer the majority of your questions. In regard to the dynamically linked libraries (`dll` or `so`), they are built on the fly. You develop your package, including the C code. Once you want to install the library from source (e.g. using `R CMD INSTALL spam`), or create a binary distribution, the C code will be compiled into the appropriate library file.

Comment: Thanks this and @Martin Morgan comment helped me greatly.

Answer (score 4):

Faced with similar headaches I switched to C++ in combination with Rcpp. Rcpp takes care of all the headaches for you in compiling packages:

http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html

There is also an entire vignette on how to build a package using Rcpp:

http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-package.pdf